# How to execute a block of code in PHP once per day in main template file? Non cron

Tags: php, cron

I have a block of PHP code that generates my sitemap.xml file. Problem is, it generates the file every time a site page is loaded. The code is in my main template file.

How could I tell PHP to only execute this code say, once per day, instead of every time the template is loaded?

I don't want to use cron tab because the code needs to be in the template file. The template file is pulled for multiple domains on the same account. So I need to put a condition on the block of code that says `only run this code when a page is loaded but only during a certain time frame each day, like from 12 noon to 4pm or something like that`.

I know that is what cron is for, but need it done in PHP.

**UPDATE**

So this is what I came up with based on `Travesty3` answer.

```
$time  = time();
$sitemap = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/sitemap.xml';
if ($time - filemtime($sitemap) >= 1*24*60*60) { // 1 days

(generate sitemap code here)

}
```

This works fine. The sitemap is now only being generated once per day only if the site has at least 1 visitor per day.

But if the site has a lot of traffic which was my original concern for doing this in the first place, won't checking the `filemtime` of the sitemap.xml file cause almost the same amount of overhead on the server as generating the sitemap file on each request?

Comment: Assuming you have a database running, you can save a timestamp into your database, so you can always ping back when you should update. (Better than pinging the filesystem)

Comment: currently only using arrays and no database.

Comment: I don't see why Travesty3's answer wouldn't work. Just check the last modified time on sitemap.xml, and if it's way out of date, do your updates.

Comment: oh, I was checking it on the actual page that gets loaded. Be right back with results.

Comment: The pitfall in this is when no one visits your website. But then you don't need to worry about the sitemap being out of date anyways.

Comment: Exactly why I pointed out using a database would be less overhead than a filesystem. You should be using a database for a large server in the first place anyways. I can only think of two methods, the current one you have (but move it to a database instead), or an automated system to do this for you (i.e cron).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the [`filemtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) on the generated file and only generate it on page load if it's over 24 hours old.

Also, you can use cron to execute a PHP script or call a URL. So there's also that.

Comment: the deal with filemtime is it checks when file was last modified. I need to check when page was last viewed by a web user. Not when I last modified the file.

Comment: used your suggestion. I updated my question with the results and another concern. Would you mind revisiting my question and give your thoughts.