# How Can I Allow A PHP Script to Only Run Once Per Day?

Tags: php, cron

How can I allow a PHP script to run once per day even if it is launched multiple times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run PHP script in certain interval (e.g. once a day)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/865381/how-can-i-run-php-script-in-certain-interval-e-g-once-a-day)

Comment: All you had to do was [Google](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=How+Can+I+Make+A+PHP+Script+Only+Run+Once+Per+Day) your title. Please put some effort in in researching before asking questions.

Comment: Use cron jobs :), welcome to SO :)

Comment: By using Cron jobs

Comment: **[Cronless](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26154395/how-to-execute-a-block-of-code-in-php-once-per-day-in-main-template-file-non-cr)** - By the way, it was the first result of Googling your title.

Comment: The comments here are a bit harsh. I think the point was that it should only run once a day even if lauched serveral times a day. Just saying 'use cron' doesn't answer that question fully. Something like: "Make sure your cron job only runs once a day, and don't put the script on a public server.", could have been added.

Comment: Thanks, @KIKOSoftware. However, how would I  "Make sure your cron job only runs once a day."

Comment: @Nathan: Two ways: 1. Do not put it in a public webserver directory so other people can run it. 2. Register the time it runs somewhere, and check that value when running it again at the beginning of the PHP script.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware That seems like it would work. But I don't know PHP that well, so could you give me the code to do that?

Comment: @Nathan. I'm sorry, storing a value and retrieving it, and comparing date/times, are very basic operations. You can find examples everywhere. Here on Stack Overflow it is always appreciated if you, at least, show some effort to find a solution yourself. If you cannot make it work, ask a new question and show what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

on a linux server use cron , you will be able to choose what frequency it will be run : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

on a windows server :

[What is the Windows version of cron?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron)

after your edit : see @script47's comment

*By the way, cron is very simple to use, dont be affraid of it*

Comment: and a non Linux server?

Comment: So why not make you answer more complete and include that link your question?

Comment: Hi. I don't want to set it to run at a specific time every day. I want the php script only to be able to run once a day. It doesn't matter what day it is. :) Thanks!